# Button content is not showing with inner controlTemplate

Tags: wpf

I created a grid with two buttons, i created an inner template for the first button; and button template in resources for the second one.
the problem is that i don't understand why the inner template don't show the content of the button ???

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
            <Border BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="2" Background="Red" TextBlock.Foreground="White">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Button_A" >
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate >
                    <Border BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="2" Background="Red" TextBlock.Foreground="White">
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Button_B" Template="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}">
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Your "inner" controltemplate, without `TargetType="Button"`, throws an exception for me on startup. When I add `TargetType="Button"`, it displays the content. In XAML editor Design mode, it displays the content either way.

Comment: thank you for the answer. i thought that the inner template refers to the parent and don't have to specify the targetType !!!

Comment: Nope, it’s just a different way of setting the same property